# How to open next page in Flutter when using Redux with API calls

Tags: dart, flutter

So I have a login page and when user pressed login, the middleware makes API calls and after the response is received the reducer changes the app state (`isLogged` in is set to `true`). How do I go the the next page using Navigator. When I try to do it, the error is thrown that the setResult() was called during building. 
When the state changes, the widget tree is rebuilt so the navigator doesn't get appropriate context. How do I wait for the tree to be rebuilt and then call the Navigator.of(context).push(Route).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vattendance_flutter/common/loading_status.dart';
import 'package:vattendance_flutter/common/ui/buttons/primary_button.dart';
import 'package:vattendance_flutter/common/ui/loading/primary_circular_progress.dart';
import 'package:vattendance_flutter/common/ui/text_fields.dart';
import 'package:flutter_redux/flutter_redux.dart';
import 'package:vattendance_flutter/redux/app/app_state.dart';
import 'package:redux/redux.dart';
import 'package:vattendance_flutter/redux/login/login_actions.dart';
import 'package:vattendance_flutter/ui/home/home_page.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  _ViewModel _viewModel;
  TextEditingController _usernameController;
  TextEditingController _passwordController;

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _usernameController = TextEditingController();
    _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, _ViewModel>(
      converter: (store) => _ViewModel.fromStore(store),
      builder: (context, viewModel) {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        _stateDependentSetUp();
        return StoreBuilder<AppState>(
          rebuildOnChange: true,
          onDidChange: (store) {},
          builder: (context, viewModel) {
            return Scaffold(
              key: scaffoldKey,
              resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
              body: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'VAttendance',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 40.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 40.0,
                      left: 16.0,
                      right: 16.0,
                    ),
                    child: PrimaryTextField(
                      controller: _usernameController,
                      hintText: "Username",
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 40.0,
                      left: 16.0,
                      right: 16.0,
                    ),
                    child: PrimaryTextField(
                      controller: _passwordController,
                      hintText: "Password",
                      obsecureText: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                    child: _getLoginButtonOrProgress(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  _stateDependentSetUp() {
    var loadingData = _viewModel.loadingData;
    if (_viewModel.loadingData.status == LoadingStatus.ERROR) {
      scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text(loadingData.message ?? "Error")));
    } else if (_viewModel.loadingData.status == LoadingStatus.SUCCESS) {
      scaffoldKey.currentState
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Welcome to VAttendance.")));
      _startHome();
    }
  }

  _getLoginButtonOrProgress() {
    return _viewModel.loadingData.status == LoadingStatus.LOADING
        ? PrimaryCircularProgress(
            progressColor: Colors.blue,
          )
        : PrimaryButton(
            text: "Login",
            onPressed: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
              _viewModel.onLoginPressed(
                username: _usernameController.text,
                password: _passwordController.text,
              );
            });
  }

  _startHome() {
         Navigator.of(scaffoldKey.currentContext).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return HomePage();
              },
            ),
          );
  }
}

class _ViewModel {
  final bool isLoggedIn;
  final LoadingData loadingData;
  final Function({String username, String password, Function onError})
      onLoginPressed;

  _ViewModel({
    this.loadingData,
    this.onLoginPressed,
    this.isLoggedIn,
  });

  factory _ViewModel.fromStore(Store<AppState> store) {
    return _ViewModel(
      isLoggedIn: store.state.loginState.isLoggedIn,
      loadingData: store.state.loginState.loadingData,
      onLoginPressed: ({String username, String password, Function onError}) {
        store.dispatch(LoginAction(username: username, password: password));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add a [Completer](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html) to your `LoginAction` so it will have 3 fields: `username`, `password` and `completer`.

When you pass this completer to your `LoginAction`:

```
Completer _initCompleter() {
  return new Completer()
    ..future.then((_) => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("\someRoute"));
}
```

Completer will wait until the `Future` gets there.
In the middleware you can invoke `complete()` method to tell the widget to go to next screen.

This is inside middleware logic:

```
authService.loginInWithEmail(action.email, action.password).then(
  (user) {
    store.dispatch(new UserProvidedAction(user));
    action.completer?.complete();
  },
);
```

You can also use this to handle errors, just add to completer's future `onError` parameter and then in the middleware you can call `completeError()`.

Comment: I think this should be the answer while waiting for flutter redux to update with promise dispatch